# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState onBackPressed

Tags: illegalstateexception, onbackpressed, onsaveinstancestate

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

App is crashing in this method of the Activity.
No async is called from activity.
Cause

Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Seen all the related question but didnt get any solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution?